# parameterized function invoked without arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def snd(pair):
    x,y = pair
    return y

list_of_tuples = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,0)]
print(min(list_of_tuples, key=snd(list_of_tuples)))
```

the above function takes pair as an argument but when tries calling it, it is called without any arguments.
Why so?

Answer (score 1):

Many functions in Python have an optional `key` argument that takes a callable (a function) that is applied on each of the elements (here, each tuple pair).

You don't *need* to supply the argument yourself, `min` does that for you. From the [docs on `min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

> There are two optional keyword-only arguments. The key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for `list.sort()`.

Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) for additional information on key functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost correct, just indent after snd defintion and only use the function name for key argument as min function will automatically pass the list as an argument to the function.

```
def snd(pair):
  x,y = pair
  return y

list_of_tuples = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,0)]
print(min(list_of_tuples, key=snd))
```